# How to properly use batch normalization during inference

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, batch-normalization

I am trying to manually implement calculations of the image classification process using pre-trained weights from the MobilenetV2 network. I know how to apply filter weights to the channels, but not sure what to do with the coefficients from the batch normalization (BN) layers. The model uses BN after each convolution before ReLu6. As explained in many sources, BN has a lot of benefits during model training. The [original Mobilenetv2 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf) does say that they used BN during training, but nothing about using it during testing. The pre-trained MobilenetV2 model comes with BN layers which contain weights 4 x n_channels (I assume gamma, beta, mean, and std for each input featuremap in the BN layer). The following questions is:

1. How do I apply the four coefficients to a featuremap during inference? (This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-theory-and-how-to-use-it-with-tensorflow-1892ca0173ad) explains it, but I still don't get it - aren't those imported coefficients already pre-calculated, so the operation on a featuremap is reduced to a multiply-add?)

The [original paper on BN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) in section 3.1 says:

> ... Since the means and variances are fixed during inference,
>   the normalization is simply a linear transform applied to
>   each activation. It may further be composed with the scaling by γ and shift by β, to yield a single linear transform
>   that replaces BN(x)...

Does this mean that during inference I would use **only *gamma* and *beta* coefficients** to "scale and shift" each pixel of a corresponding feature map? That is, something like:

```
for ch
  for row
    for col
      out_feature[row][col][ch] = in_feature[row][col][ch] * BN[gamma][ch] + BN[beta][ch]
```

Could anyone, please, confirm and explain if this is correct and re-iterate what exactly is expected from the BN layer output in terms of value ranges (before ReLu6)?